# PHP: How to generate psd to png converted image as a merged image instead several one?

Tags: php, magento

I can generate png image from psd file by `exec("convert  -resize 406x238\! 'input/home.psd' 'output/newhome.png' ");` . But this is generating so many png files. The reason is psd image has several layers. I can take first image by just specifying `'input/home.psd[0]'` But I need to take all layers as merged so that I can get a single image. Just like screen-shot of the psd file. Is there any way to do this with this kind of command or with ghost script? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12518902/1332068

Comment: @Axel I need something as a command string like the string inside exec(). Also that solution also seems like not merging layers.

Comment: -layers merge this is doing the trick